# How is this exception being caused and what alternative could be employed?

Tags: c#, linq, namespaces, rss

Picking up an exception that I don't understand. Would really like some help if anyone could put their mind on it. Consuming other tested RSS feeds and having no issue however the latest test candidate is giving me a headache.

```
Line 499 is the one in the query: select new {
Line 517 is the opening statement of the foreach.
```

> ----   at System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace.op_Addition(XNamespace ns, String localName)    at
>   rssRepub.MainForm.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__2(XElement item) in
>   c:\Documents and Settings\Andrew Seabrook\My
>   Documents\development\rssPub\rssRepub_0.5\rssRepub\MainForm.cs:line
>   499    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at rssRepub.MainForm.Completed(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs
>   e) in c:\Documents and Settings\Andrew Seabrook\My
>   Documents\development\rssPub\rssRepub_0.5\rssRepub\MainForm.cs:line
>   517
>
> ----Value cannot be null. Parameter name: ns

```
        try
        {                       

            toolStripStatusLabelMain.Text = "Download completed!";
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(INSTALLPATH + "id.xslt");
            transform.Transform(INSTALLPATH + "tempfeed.txt", INSTALLPATH + "clean.xml");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INSTALLPATH + "clean.xml");

            Dictionary<String, String> dbdata = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            var db = new MSAccess();
            string feedID =  db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT feedID FROM Feeds WHERE feedURL = '" + tvMain.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString() + "'");


            XNamespace dcNs = doc.Element("rss").GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dc");
            XNamespace slashNs = doc.Element("rss").GetNamespaceOfPrefix("slash");
            //XNamespace slashNs = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/";

            var data = from item in doc.Root.Descendants().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "channel").Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "item")
                      select new {
                            Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value,
                            Link = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Value,
                            PublishDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "pubDate").Value),
                            Creator = item.Element(dcNs + "creator").Value,
                            Guid = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "guid").Value,                
                            Description = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value,
                            //Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value,
                            Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value,
                            //Comments = item.Element("slash:comments").Value
                            Comments = item.Element(slashNs + "comments").Value,
                            //Comments = item.SelectSingleNode("slash:comments", nameSpace).InnerText
                            Categories = (from category in item.Elements("category")
                                          orderby category.Value
                                          select category.Value).ToList()

            };

            foreach (var item in data)
            {

                var csv = string.Join( ";", item.Categories );

                //add feed to database
                dbdata.Add("fiFeedID", feedID);
                dbdata.Add("fiTitle", item.Title);
                dbdata.Add("fiLink", item.Link);
                dbdata.Add("fiPubDate", item.PublishDate.ToString());
                //if (item.Creator != null) 
                dbdata.Add("fiCreator", item.Creator);
                dbdata.Add("fiGuid", item.Guid);
                dbdata.Add("fiDescription", item.Description);                  
                dbdata.Add("fiContent", item.Content);  
                //if (item.Comments != null) 
                dbdata.Add("fiComments", item.Comments);
                dbdata.Add("fiTags",csv);

                try
                {
                    db.Insert("FeedItems", dbdata);
                }
                catch(Exception crap)
                {
                    OutCrap(crap);
                } 
                dbdata.Clear();

            }
            UpdateStatus("Fetching " + tvMain.SelectedNode.Name);
            UpdateDGVMain();
        }
        catch (Exception crap)
        {
            OutCrap(crap);
        }
```

Comment: Could you highlight which line is throwing the exception and a sample RSS feed that causes it?

Comment: What is the value of `dcNs` and `slashNs` here? Are they `null`? or non-`null`?

Comment: @T.Kiley It trips on the foreach line. The feed is http://feeds.feedburner.com/esmetravels - I note that what is different with this feed is that the tags have attributes <slash:comments xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">0</slash:comments> and <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Esme</dc:creator> wheras the previous ones were simple <dc:creator>

Comment: @MarcGravell yes indeed they are null I was thrown on this because the error speaks of the generic 'ns' rather than a specific slashNs or dcNs - silly. I will need to handle this differently then?

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook yeah; normally you can just hard-code the namespaces...

Comment: @T.Kiley How do I do that - before the issue with attributes - previously I tried: Comments = item.Element("slash:comments").Value - I cant remember but eith it blow it out or did not extract the value. And I think I also tried it without the ns, i.e. just ...Element("comments")...  same deal. Or do you mean as direct assignment i.e. XNamespace slashNs = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"

Comment: OK yes the latter fixes things! Appreciate it guys!